# jupyterのcsvファイルの読み込みについて

Tags: python

jupyterでエクセルファイルをアップロードしたのちに確認すると

Error! C:\Users\user\sample.xlsx is not UTF-8 encoded
Saving disabled.
See Console for more details.

というものが出てきます。
保存形式を変えても同様です。

原因が全く分からないのですが、どうすればいいのですが

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　タイトルがCSVファイルとなっていますが、質問文はxlsxファイルになっています。結局お試しになったのはどちらなのでしょうか？　また、エラーコードが同じでもプログラムによって対処が違うことはよくあるので、可能であれば動かしているプログラムも追記して頂けませんでしょうか。質問文下の「編集」から直接追記して頂ければと思います。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter上でNotebook（ipynb形式）ではないファイルをクリックすると、テキストとして開いて編集画面を出します。その際サポートされる文字コードはUTF-8のみのようです。

最近のエクセルでは内部的にはXMLが使われておりテキストデータと言えますが、`*.xlsx` にまとめる際にはzipで圧縮されて、バイナリーファイルとなっています。これはそのままでは Jupyter で開けません。一方、「CSV」形式というのは、テキストデータですのでUTF-8であればクリックして開けます。

`*.xlsx` と `*.csv` の違いや、文字コードについて理解し、使用している表計算ソフトなどで目的の形式で保存、あるいは変換する方法を調べて下さい。CSV形式で保存できたとしても、UTF-8 であるとは限らず、Shift JISになっていることもあります。「エクセル csv utf-8」といった語で検索すれば、だいたい解ると思います。

---

ただし、JupyterでCSV形式のファイルを開いて編集することに特に意味は無いと思います。メインのNotebookのおまけとして、簡素なテキストエディタが付属しているだけであって、それ以上の機能は有りませんので。